# Sequelize associate creating both userId and user_id for one model, but not the other

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Two models 'Agency' and 'Agent'. Each is associated to my 'User' model. I've specified a 'foreignKey' of 'user_id' for each model. However, Sequelize creates a 'userId' additionally to 'user_id' for one model but not the other, where only 'user_id' is created.

EDIT:

My User model makes the following associations:

```
  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.agency)
  }

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.agent)
  }
```

How can this be fixed to not have the 'userId' ?

Currently, the following tables are created in MySQL.

```
AGENCY

+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address1  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address2  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zipCode   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| license   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

AGENT

+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| license   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| headline  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userId    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My code is as follows:

```
// FILE agency.js

module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {

  const Agency = sequelize.define('agency', {
    id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    address1: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    address2: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    city: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    state: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    zipCode: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    country: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    license: {
      type: type.STRING
    }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
  })

  Agency.associate = (models) => {
    Agency.belongsTo(models.user, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'user_id'
      }
    })
  }

  return Agency

}


// FILE agent.js

module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {

  const Agent = sequelize.define('agent', {
    id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      required: true
    },
    license: {
      type: type.STRING
    },
    headline: {
      type: type.STRING
    }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
  })

  Agent.associate = (models) => {
    Agent.belongsTo(models.user, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'user_id'
      }
    })
  }

  return Agent

}


// FILE db.js

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config').db

const db = {}

let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config)

db.user = require('./user')(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.agency = require('./agency.js')(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.agent = require('./agent.js')(sequelize, Sequelize)

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if(db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Comment: Please add user model too

Answer (score 3):

You might have defined this in your User model :

```
User.hasOne(Agent)
// In this case hasOne will add an attribute userId to the Agent model!
```

**As per your code change this :**

```
User.hasMany(models.agency);
User.hasMany(models.agent);
```

**To :**

```
User.hasMany(models.agent,{foreignKey : 'user_id'});
User.hasMany(models.agency,{foreignKey : 'user_id'});
```

**Reason** : if you dont define foreignKey it will create `userID` own

---

> **Difference between HasOne and BelongsTo:** **[DOC REF](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto)**
>
> HasOne and BelongsTo insert the association key in different models
>   from each other. HasOne inserts the association key in target model
>   whereas BelongsTo inserts the association key in the source model.
>
> When information about association is present in source model we can
>   use belongsTo. In this case Player is suitable for belongsTo because
>   it has teamId column.
>
> ```
> Player.belongsTo(Team)  // `teamId` will be added on Player / Source model
> ```
>
> When information about association is present in target model we can
>   use hasOne. In this case Coach is suitable for hasOne because Team
>   model store information about its Coach as coachId field.
>
> ```
> Coach.hasOne(Team)  // `coachId` will be added on Team / Target model
> ```

Comment: Thanks Vivek, my User model defines the following associations:   User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.agency)
  }

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.agent)
  }